# Array of Arrays in JavaScript. Replacement for querySnapshot.forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I got this.

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

It outputs the following.

```js
0  =>  Object
1 =>  Object
2  =>  Object
```

I want an array of arrays. Just like this.

```js
[[0],
 [1],
 [2]]
```

Please help

Comment: You're not interested in doing anything with the document data?  You just want the array indexes?

Comment: For the moment, yes.

Comment: I got this                                                                                                                           for (let i = 0; i < querySnapshot.size; i++) {
  child_array.push(querySnapshot.docs[i].id);
  array.push(child_array);
}

Comment: You don't need an alternative to forEach. You just need to build an array as you iterate the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I'm new to programming, so I fully appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can create and external array and push you values in there like so:

```
const array = [];

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  array.push([doc.id])
});

console.log(array); // [[0],[1],[2]]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. It's my first question here, so, I fully appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach into `docs` of the [snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), you get an array and can use all array operations, such as `map`:

```
const arr = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => [doc.id]);
console.log(arr);
```